# Asp.net hosted multiple blazor apps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I dividing my website into multiple blazor apps in which each module should be routed by a sub path eg:
products module should be accessed by the url "domain/products"
etc.

so in the configure method in my asp.net core server project when calling

```
app.UseBlazor<Products.Startup>()
```

whats the proper way to rout all the single page app url through "domain/products/*"

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can host your blazor app in a sub folder with:

`app.Map("/subfolder", child => { child.UseBlazor<Blazor.Program>(); });`

And change the basepath of your blazor app in the index.html like this:

`<base href="/subfolder/" />`

Comment: is there any way to keep the href of the base tag unchanged

Comment: Not that I know of, it is needed for routing, so maybe if you are not using that

Comment: because changing href would  for example make accessing apis endpoints either harder or imposipple

Comment: No, not at all. You can happily use any url for your backend calls, I'm doing that all the time. The base href in index.html has no effect on that.

Comment: app.Map(...) part is no more applicable in the latest version. Only changing the <base href="/subfolder/" /> is required.

Answer (score 0):

If your like me that's looking for this now, this will get you what you need (as far as I can tell)

```
            app.Map("/site1", app =>
            {
                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseAuthorization();
                app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Site1.Startup>();
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Darixidor.Site.Startup>("index.html");
                });
            });
```